# How to centre a table according to the width and height of the computer screen?

Tags: html, css, height, width

I have found many answers to this question but they just end up centering it horizontally and not vertically.

```
<table width="200" border="1">
<tr>
<th height="200" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/7JeCb/

Comment: Vertically but not horizontally!

Comment: @Explosion Pills, depends of the height of this table. I'd rather achieved it with body's 100% height style and display table-cell.

Comment: @EL would be nice, but I don't think that's possible with pure CSS.

Comment: @Explosion Pills, yeah you're right. http://jsfiddle.net/7JeCb/10/ that's the old way, but still working =)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit silly, but vertically aligning non-table cells inside blocks is really hard.  You have to know the height of the element (and it has to have a set height).  Yours does, though, via the `th`.

```
table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

If you don't want the table to have `absolute` positioning, or if the height/width are not known, you have to use JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/7JeCb/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
  <table style="left:50%; top:50%; position:relative;">
    <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these techniques require knowing the height or width of the element being centered.

## Pseudo Elements

http://jsfiddle.net/7JeCb/12/

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

table {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

body:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -.25em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

## Flexbox

http://jsfiddle.net/7JeCb/11/

```
body, html {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```